# Как убрать квадратную тень у круглой imagebutton?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, imagebutton

Есть разметка:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/delete_group_button"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_oval"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_trash_can_outline"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

и есть два файлика в папке drawable для фона:
1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="false">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
                <corners android:radius="28dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:bottom="2dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
                <corners android:radius="28dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- we define background color -->
    <!--<solid android:color="#c0c0c0" />-->

    <!-- we define border color and thick -->
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#c0c0c0" />

    <!-- add some padding for text inside -->
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />

    <!-- we define corner radius, note that radius can be different for each corner -->
    <corners android:radius="28dp" />

</shape>
```

уже неделю сижу и бьюсь над проблемой - у меня возле этой кнопки постоянно висит квадратная тень. Не могу понять как ее убрать, сделал фон отдельно для кнопки и для layout но не помогло, тень все-равно висит и не хочет убираться. Надеюсь кто-то сможет помочь в данной ситуации, потому что моих знаний не хватает для решения этой проблемы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как ни странно решил свою проблему. В разметке кнопки нужно забрать строку:

```
android:elevation="8dp"
```

может конечно это не то что нужно было делать в моей ситуации, но мне помогло.

Comment: Да, это именно то. Параметр устанавливает высоту "поднятия" элемента над фоном. А если нет поднятия, то нет и тени.

Comment: просто у меня есть желание сделать такую тень как и у обычной стандартной floating button, но пока мои попытки не увенчались успехом